# Python - init argument not used in self

Tags: python, python-class

I came by a code and wanted to get more understanding on when to use such arrangement.
What would be a good scenario of not using `__init__`'s argument (`name`) in `self`?

```
class ArgumentNotUsedInSelf:
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.type = "user"

user_one = ArgumentNotUsedInSelf("Mike")
print(user_one.type)
```

Any explanations from architectural (and not only) point of view are most welcome!

Comment: An argument might conditionally not be used, but an argument that is never under any circumstances used? I can't imagine a use case for that.

Comment: When the interface being implemented requires it but the implementation doesn't need it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the reasons for this can be:

- Historical. The class used to use the argument, but it was changed so it's no longer meaningful. The argument was kept for backward compatibility.
- Class hierarchy. This may be a child class of a class that uses the argument, but the child overrides the need for it. The argument is required for compatibility with the parent.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of Barmar's historical example... let's say:

- `ArgumentNotUsedInSelf` used to do something with `name`, but now doesn't.
- But `name` is still used in `SubClass`, and changing everything could mess up dependent programs.

```
class ArgumentNotUsedInSelf:
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.type = "user"

class SubClass(ArgumentNotUsedInSelf):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(SubClass, self).__init__(name)
        self.name = name

x = SubClass('Mike')
print(x.name, x.type)
```

Output:

```
Mike user
```

Answer (score -4):

This would be helpful if you want to store the field "name" of the created object and re-use it later:

```
class ArgumentNotUsedInSelf:
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.type = "user"
        self.name = name

user_one = ArgumentNotUsedInSelf("Mike")
print(user_one.type)
print(user_one.name)
```

Comment: Thank you. I do know that. My questions however is not about bringing `name` into self.